# Default Customization in Epicor 10.1

Tags: epicorerp

I'm working in Epicor 10.1 SaaS writing a customization on New PO Suggestions.  The customization works and I can access it through Developer mode.  I'm trying to allow users to always see this customization when they launch New PO Suggestions, but there are at least two entry points: from the Main Menu and from the Buyer's Workbench.  In the past, I've created a new Main Menu Icon and made it the only visible icon for all users; however, this would not work in this case, because most users access New PO Suggestions from the Buyers Workbench.  This Process calls:

```
Process Key: Erp.UI.POSuggEntry
Calling App: Erp.UI.BuyerWorkbenchEntry
Menu ID: PMGO2011
```

How can I direct users to the customization in all cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to make other applications call the customization by:

1) Creating a customized Menu Item for New PO Suggestion with a new Menu ID
2) Opening Process Calling Maintenance, creating a new Process, and entering the Called Process Reference "Erp.UI.POSuggEntry", leaving Called From blank, and entering the new Menu ID